# PHP. I want to allow user to add file to form, from any folder

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my form [image]

It gets the url of the image, and save it in the database. But it can show only files saved in folder "uploads", so I want to allow user to add file from any place of the PC. Help please
Maybe I can do smth in the store.php?

Create.php

```
<form style="width: 25em; text-align: center; align-items: center;" action="store.php" method="POST">
     
  <div class="mb-2 form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="mb-2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Name">
   
  </div>
  <div class="mb-2 form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="mb-2">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Surname">
  </div>

 <div class="mb-2 form-group">
    <label for="inputPatronym" class="mb-2">Patronym:</label>
    <input type="text" name="patronym" class="form-control"placeholder="Patronym">
  </div>

                         

  <div class="mb-2 form-group">
    <label for="inputPatronym" class="mb-2">Biography:</label>
    <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control"placeholder="Biography">
  </div>


<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Image</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="userfile" type="file" id="formFile" accept=".img,.png,.jpeg,.jpg,.bmp">
</div>

<div class="mb-4 form-group">
    

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Save</button>


  </div>
     <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-3" href="/postati.php" role="button">Return</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Store .php

```
<?php 
    require_once __DIR__ . "/database/pdo.php";

    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $Surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $Patronym = $_POST['patronym'];
    $Description = $_POST['description'];
    $userfile = $_POST['userfile'];
    
   
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `peoples` (`Name`, `Surname`, `Patronym`, `Description`, `userfile`) VALUES (:name, :surname, :patronym, :description, :userfile)";

    $params = [
        "name" => $Name,
        "surname" => $Surname,
        "patronym" => $Patronym,
        "description" => $Description,
        "userfile" => $userfile,
    ];

    $prepare = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $prepare->execute($params);

    $pdo->lastInsertId();
    $lastInsertId=$pdo->lastInsertId();


header("Location: /postati.php")
    
?>
```

View

```
<div class="image text-center">
  <img src="uploads/<?=$people['userfile']?>" width="250px" height="350px" class="center">
</div>
```

I tried to move the file with move_uploaded_file, but then the other variables are not saving.

Comment: Just change „uploads/„ from your image src attribute and point to the right folder instead - but it seems you didn‘t finish the upload and move file process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` declaration in your form. You need this if you want a file upload form.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="store.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: If I use enctype, I get an error: Column 'userfile' cannot be null

Comment: on your post script, `var_dump($_POST); exit;` to see if stuff has indeed been uploaded, then use move_uploaded_file

Comment: Uploaded files are available in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`